# Retrieving data from WCF service

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have database with two tables - `Groups` and `Items`.

- Table `Groups` has only two columns: `Id` and `Name`.
- Table `Items` has three columns: `Id`, `GroupId` and `Name`.

As you can see, there is one-to-many relation between `Groups` and `Items`.

I'm trying to build a web service using WCF and LINQ. I've added new LINQ to SQL classes file, and I've imported these two tables. Visual Studio has automatically generated proper classes for me.

After that, I've create simple client for the service, just to check if everything is working. After I call `GetAllGroups()` method, I get all groups from `Groups` table. But their property `Items` is always null.

So my question is - is there a way to force WCF to return whole class (whole `Group` class and all `Items` that belong to it)? Or is this the way it should behave?

EDIT: This is function inside WCF Service that returns all `Groups`:

```
    public List<Group> GetAllGroups()
    {
        List<Group> groups = (from r in db.Groups select r).ToList();

        return groups;
    }
```

I've checked while debugging and every `Group` object inside `GetAllGroups()` function has it's items, but after client receives them - every `Items` property is set to `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you're experiencing the default "lazy-loading" behavior of Linq-to-SQL. When you debug and look at the `.Items` collection - that causes the items to be loaded. This doesn't happen however when your service code runs normally.

You can however enforce "eager-loading" of those items - try something like this:
(*see [Using DataLoadOptions to Control Deferred Loading](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/06/linq-to-sql-deferred-loading-lazy-load.aspx) or [LINQ to SQL, Lazy Loading and Prefetching](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Oct/12/LINQ-to-SQL-Lazy-Loading-and-Prefetching) for more details*)

```
public List<Group> GetAllGroups()
{
    // this line should really be where you *instantiate* your "db" context!
    db.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

    DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
    dlo.LoadWith<Group>(g => g.Items);

    db.LoadOptions = dlo;

    List<Group> groups = (from r in db.Groups select r).ToList();

    return groups;
}
```

Do you get the `Items` collection populated now, when you call your service?

Comment: Is it possible to somehow specify that I want everything loaded?